# Python: Grabbing X,Y coordinate from matching fields

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-desktop, table

[image]

Here is my table. What I am trying to do is write a python script to go over the Zip_Crid values. If there are matching values, I need to grab x1, y1, x2, y2 and put it in a new field. Haven't really worked with python before, where should I begin?

Comment: You'll probably want to look at SearchCursors to identify matching pairs, and UpdateCursors to add values to your new field.

Comment: how do you identify matching pairs using SearchCursors?

Comment: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000 search cursor help... if you need an intro to python and ARCGIS https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/17 will help you a lot. i believe search cursors is covered in unit 3

Answer (score 2):

I suggest one approach could be to first summarise the Zip_Crid field using [Frequency (Analysis)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001w000000).  This will give you an output table where you have a frequency for each unique value of Zip_Crid.  Sub-select the table for all those where the frequency is greater than 1. Then iterate the result with a search cursor (as directed in the comments by RyanDalton +1).  Using the value of the Zip_Crid field from your sub-selected frequency table, select on your original table to give you a subset of rows that match and then assemble your new field.

The reason I suggest this approach is that otherwise you will have to re-search the entire original table for every row (which is potentially a LOT of duplication and on a large table will be very slow).

As you are new to Python (and even if you weren't) I suggest you rough out your process using [Model Builder](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002w00000001000000) and then export to a Python script. It will be very verbose and messy code but it will point you in the right direction (when combined with the documentation).

Comment: If you have only Basic level license Summary Statistics can be used in place of Frequency